# How to run command on a remote-file

Tags: python, unix

I am running the following command on my local machine:

```
xml val -e -s file1.xsd.xml file2.xml
```

How would I do that with a file from s3? For example:

```
xml val -e -s file1.xsd.xml https://s3.aws.com/file
```

Is there a way to stream the contents to the file? I would prefer not to have to download the file and then open it locally.

Comment: You need to either ship the code to the data or (effectively) download the data and run the command on it.

Comment: Whether the former is possible will depend on S3's API's for uploading arbitrary code, but it seems unlikely that they would let you do that.

Comment: You may probably use `wget` or `curl` to download a file first i.e.: `xml .... <(wget -q -O - https://s3.aws.com/file)` (but you'll get a local copy). But since its amazon S3, maybe it is easier to mount filesystem i.e. with https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse ?

Comment: you're using the `val`(idate) option. Do you just want to know the remote file is valid? Run your 2nd cmd and then `echo $?`. Try with known good and known bad files. Do you get any difference on `$?`? But it sounds like you want to update the remote file, for that you'd at least have to use the `ed` but I don't see a `--net` option. The `tr` function does support `--net`, but I think in all cases, `--net` is a read-only function. (I'm just getting started with a deep dive in xmlstarlet documentation, so will be happy for a guru to offer a solution. This would be interesting) Good luck.